# PostGreSql ISNULL or Coalesce in sub queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

Well, densed down I have a table with a timestamp column. I have to return all records from that table where the timestamp is after a given point of time (= timeX) but PLUS the last record timeX.

My approach was to number the entries ordered by the timestamp. Then subselect the number of the first record after timeX (= numX). And return all records where the number is larger than numX-1.

A test setup

```
  CREATE TABLE public.events
  (
    id integer,
    name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    happens timestamp without time zone
  );

  INSERT INTO events (id, name, happens)
  VALUES
  (1, 'event 7', '2018-08-01 07:00:00.000000'),
  (2, 'event 6', '2018-08-01 06:00:00.000000'),
  (3, 'event 2', '2018-08-01 02:00:00.000000'),
  (4, 'event 5', '2018-08-01 05:00:00.000000'),
  (5, 'event 1', '2018-08-01 01:00:00.000000'),
  (6, 'event 8', '2018-08-01 08:00:00.000000'),
  (7, 'event 5.2', '2018-08-01 05:00:00.000000'),
  (8, 'event 4', '2018-08-01 04:00:00.000000'),
  (9, 'event 3', '2018-08-01 03:00:00.000000');
```

My current query

```
  WITH AllEvents AS (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY happens) AS num,
      id,
      name,
      happens
    FROM events
    ORDER BY num
  )
  SELECT * FROM AllEvents ae
  WHERE ae.num >= 
  (
    SELECT Num-1
    FROM AllEvents
    WHERE happens >= '2018-08-01 02:30:00'
    LIMIT 1
  );
```

The query works well at '2018-08-01 02:30:00' because the select finds an entry for which the num can be returned.

If I try to select for '2018-08-01 17:30:00' the query does not find a record so the returned num is null and the result is an empty list instead of the last record.

I tried to fix that with ISNULL or COALESCE and MAX(ae.num) but I couldn't get it to work.

Any hint I could get the null check done and return the last record (which would equal Max(ae.num)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this simpler?:

```
select * from events
where happens >= 
(select max(happens) from events
    WHERE happens < '2018-08-01 02:30:00');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what the logic is that you want to implement.  So, there might be a simpler method to accomplish what you want.

However, you can put the subquery in as an argument to fix your query:

```
WHERE ae.num >= COALESCE((SELECT ae2.Num - 1
                          FROM AllEvents ae2
                          WHERE ae2.happens >= '2018-08-01 02:30:00'
                          LIMIT 1
                         ), ae.num
                        );
```

You'll also notice that I added table aliases and qualified column names to the subquery.  This is a best practice to avoid problems when using subqueries.